# How to stop useSelector from invoking multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component like below -

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const bankingAccounts = useSelector(state => state.dogs);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(dogs);
  }, [dogs]);

  return <div>Demo</div>;
};
```

Here dogs returns an array of object. There are some other things going on in my app which updating the some properties of dog in the store and its is resulting in reinvoking of the above useSelector.

I have tried passing a custom equality function in useSelector, but no luck.

```
useSelector(state, areEqual)
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the reactivity, then you can use useStore [will only return the current state] instead of useSelector() [ is called every time there is an update in the state.]

```
const { getState  } = useStore()
const bankingAccounts = getState().dogs;
```